# shadow in tableview cell not working after scroll up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have shadow in my view inside tableview cell, when I scroll up the shadow not working properly. I believe it because of the state change but I don't know how to. this is my code

from this before scroll up:

[image: tableviewCell]

after scroll up:

[image: failedShadow]

```
class PerformanceKnowledgeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var hrzStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.borderColor.cgColor
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 8)
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false

        contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        clipsToBounds = false
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be connected to the actual reuse of cells. Meaning when you are scrolling, last cell is removed and inserted again. So the view's order is changed.

I was able to fix this (= maintain order) with cell's zPosition:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - indexPath.row)
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps for multi-section tables it should be: `cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - indexPath.row)`